# Create new list initiate

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want my L3 linked list to alternate the values of L1 and L2 like this
1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14

I tried the code below but i think the L3 list is reset each iteration (line "**p3=Cellule(p1.entier)**"), i cannot find a way to create L3 to solve my problem.

```
class Cellule(object):
def __init__(self, entier):
    self.entier=entier
    self.suiv=None
L1=Cellule(1)
L1.suiv=Cellule(2)
L1.suiv.suiv=Cellule(3)
L1.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(4)

L2=Cellule(11)
L2.suiv=Cellule(12)
L2.suiv.suiv=Cellule(13)
L2.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(14)

p1=L1
p2=L2
L3=Cellule(0)
p3=L3

while p1.suiv!=None:
    p3=Cellule(p1.entier)
    p3=p3.suiv
    p3=Cellule(p2.entier)
    p2=p2.suiv
    p1=p1.suiv

p4=L3
while p4.suiv!=None:
    print(p4.entier)
    p4=p4.suiv
```

I hope you can help, thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can't create a linked list where i alternate the value of my L1 list 1,2,3,4 and L2 11,12,13,14 to have 1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Cellule(object):
    def __init__(self, entier):
        self.entier=entier
        self.suiv=None

L1=Cellule(1)
L1.suiv=Cellule(2)
L1.suiv.suiv=Cellule(3)
L1.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(4)

L2=Cellule(11)
L2.suiv=Cellule(12)
L2.suiv.suiv=Cellule(13)
L2.suiv.suiv.suiv=Cellule(14)

p1=L1
p2=L2
L3=Cellule(0)
p3=L3

while 1:
    p3.suiv = Cellule(p1.entier)
    p3 = p3.suiv
    p3.suiv = Cellule(p2.entier)
    p3 = p3.suiv
    p2 = p2.suiv
    p1 = p1.suiv
    if p1 == None and p2 == None:  # I assume that your two objects are the same length
        break

p4 = L3.suiv
while p4:
    print(p4.entier)
    p4 = p4.suiv
```

If your two objects are of different lengths, you can add a judgment statement to your code.Like this:

```
while 1:
    if p1:
        p3.suiv = Cellule(p1.entier)
        p3 = p3.suiv
        p1 = p1.suiv

    if p2:
        p3.suiv = Cellule(p2.entier)
        p3 = p3.suiv
        p2 = p2.suiv

    if p1 == None and p2 == None:
        break
```

Comment: It works, but my new list is 0,1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14 and not 1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14

Comment: @PeaceAndCube if you don't want node 0,try this `L3 = L3.suiv`. I thought you wanted `p4`,so I made `p4` to be 1,11,2,12,3,13,4,14.